# My boss stopped giving me shifts what do I do?

Tags: communication, employer-relations

I was working in a bar, and was told I'd be getting 2-3 shifts per week, but now I'm not getting any and my boss stopped replying to me, what do I do?

Comment: Phone him. If that doesn't work, go to the bar and talk to him.

Comment: Or go to another bar that may have jobs.

Answer (score 7):

Look for another job, you have lost the bar job and I assume you don't have a contract.

If you really need the work, then ring your boss and try and work something out. But in my experience working bars (bouncing not barstaff) once this happens to a barman/lady that's basically it, quite often the bouncers are told not to let them in as well.

Comment: I'm upvoting this.  Did a VERY brief (and not brief enough) stint as a doorman/bouncer for a nightclub.  This happens.  It usually goes like, "Don't let that [BLEEP]ing bartender Steve *OR HIS GIRLFRIEND* back in."  Never know why, but the OP is definitely done.